# How to empty all wordpress post content via mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Is there any MySQL command that empty WordPress posts content? I have 3k posts on my WordPress site, and I want to delete everything from WordPress content via MySQL.

Wordpress post content column can be found in mysql > wp_posts > post_content.

Comment: Consider this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete Using MySql directly to delete content from WordPress is a bit like using a chainsaw to wash your kitchen floor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to keep the posts as it as (published), but want to empty only content text inside the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Wear boots and eye protection. That is, **back up your WordPress instance and database** before you do this massively destructive operation. Make sure you can restore it if you need to.

Use a database cleaner plugin (like Advanced Database Cleaner) to remove revisions, auto-drafts, and other extraneous entries from the wp_posts table.

Then give this MySQL statement from phpmyadmin or some other MySQL client.

```sql
SELECT id, post_title, SUBSTRING(post_content, 1, 20) content
  FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_type = 'post'
```

Eyeball the output to make sure these are the posts you want to blank out. Then do this

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts
   SET post_content = '', post_excerpt = '', post_content_filtered = ''
 WHERE post_type = 'post'
```

and your posts will be blanked out.

I really don't think you should touch post_types other than 'post'  without knowing a lot about how your theme and plugins handle custom posts. You definitely should avoid touching the 'attachment' type, because that will mess up your media library.

Comment: You are awesome. The code works perfectly. This is exactly what I'm looking for.